# How to measure the distance between a detected horizontal plane and the floor plane in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

iOS ARKit detects horizontal planes fine. You can also get the size of the plane easily. However, how can one measure the distance between parallel horizontal planes?

For example, how can we get the height of the table by calculating the distance between table plane and the floor plane?

[image]

We have the anchors for table plane and floor plane but I do not know if we have access to the plane equation parameters of the planes?

Comment: Are they `SCNPlane`s? If so they should have a `.position` property that you can use

Comment: Just checked the SCNPlane but there is no .position property. There are only .width and .height that correspond to the 2 dimensional size of the plane.
However, SCNNode has .position property. Is that real world position?

Comment: Sorry sorry I meant `SCNAnchor`...

Comment: The anchor's position might work... not 100% sure though

Comment: There is no SCNAnchor. I suppose you mean ARAnchor which does not have .position property either.

Even if we have positions, how are we going to calculate the distance between planes? Those are real-world coordinates of the plane centers. Point-to-point distance calculation would be wrong.

Comment: Yeah - I meant `ARAnchor`. You can get the position from that by `let anchorPosition = SCNVector3(anchor.transform.columns.3.x, anchor.transform.columns.3.y, anchor.transform.columns.3.z)`.

Comment: To calculate the distance just use [distance formula](https://github.com/aheze/AccessibleReality/blob/e73cfb433a70e6060feabfdbe178fa87103a2a23/Development/Testing/Testing%20playgrounds/Accessible%20Reality.playgroundbook/Contents/Modules/BookCore.playgroundmodule/Sources/Main/AR/MainVC%2BTrackMarker.swift#L156). Even though it's real-world positions, ARKit is pretty accurate. You should get within a centimeter in accuracy

Comment: Once again, those positions are real-world coordinates of the plane centers. If you calculate point-to-point distance as you indicated, the result does not refer to the distance between parallel planes.

Comment: Right - it returns the distance but not the perpendicular distance. In that case you can just ignore `X` and `Z`... just do `firstPlaneAnchor.transform.columns.3.y` - `secondPlaneAnchor.transform.columns.3.y`

Comment: That would also not be correct because Y coordinate of those anchors is according to the world coordinates i.e. with respect to the camera. If we have a table plane and floor plane in our scene, how can we transform anchor position of the table plane from world-space to the floor-plane-space? The floor plane anchor would be 0,0,0 point and then transformed table plane anchor's Y coordinate would be the result I am looking for.

Comment: "with respect to the camera" but `transform` is the real-life coordinates. So (0, 0, 0) will always be the same place in real life, no matter where the camera is. I am probably not following something.

Comment: Well, the camera might move and Y-axis real-world coordinates of anchor points are also changing, right? However, if we could project local (0,0,0) point of the table plane coordinate system to the coordinate system of the floor plane, the projected y coordinate would provide us the distance between the planes.
What I am asking is that how we can project a local point on a plane to another plane's coordinate system?

Comment: @bellekci Did you get the success? I am looking for the same solution